# Не получается поставить Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

У меня `HP ProBook 4730s, Windows 8`.Загрузил на флешку убунту по этой инструкции: [Установка Ubuntu с USB Flash-диска](http://ubuntulinux.ru/config/ustanovka-ubuntu-s-usb-flash-diska/).Перезагружаю комп, жму `Esc` и там выбираю `Boot Option, Hard Drive` (или как то так) В общем появляется синее окно, где я выбираю `Install Ubuntu`, после небольших настроек языка и `wifi` ноут перегружается. По идее дальше должна пойти сама установка, но у меня запускается винда, как ни в чем не бывало. Что за ерунда? Помогите плиз?P.s. ставить нужно, оставив W8

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать ВСЕ по инструкции... В частности:

1. выбрать Removable Devices (тогда загрузитесь с флешки - она и есть тот самый "Removable Device"), поскольку, выбрав "Hard Drive (или как то так)" вы указываете, что грузиться надо как обычно - с жесткого диска...
2. выбрать НЕ "Install Ubuntu", а, как указано в инструкции, "Default"

Comment: Так я и выбираю Removable Hard Drive. Потом жму Default. Выбираю Установка внутри W8, ноут перезагружается и запускается винда.. Ничего больше.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте перед инсталляцией запустить режим "Запустить Ubuntu без установки" таким образом Вы проверите совместимость Вашего железа и увидите систему в действии на Вашем оборудовании.

Comment: Я уже ставил до этого и все было норм

Answer (score 1):

Я правильно понимаю, что вы пытаетесь установить Убунту на тот же NTFS раздел, где у вас уже Windows8 стоит? Похоже, вы первый, кто это пробовал сделать.

Надо бы вот что:

1. Средствами Windows ужать имеющийся NTFS раздел до высвобождения необходимого пространства.
2. Далее следовать вот этим инструкциям:http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu иhttp://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest
3. И пользуясь этими инструкциями, установить Убунту на свободное место из п.1!

Загрузчиком там будет GRUB. Седьмую венду он подхватывает, думаю что и восьмую тоже!

А если совсем влом с этим ковыряться, то при наличии венды и и-нета можно всё сделать через вендовый инсталлер: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windowsПравда, он несовместим с восьмёркой и UEFI, но кому-то может эта инфа полезна будет.

Но в любом случае надо сперва место под убунтовый раздел освободить (см. п.1).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю на новых пк/нотах с предустановленной win8 вместо BIOS используется [UEFI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI). Если это как раз ваш случай, то почитайте: [Установка Ubuntu на новые платы с UEFI/EFI](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=167665.0).